# Asp.net MVC different routes cause relative addressing issues

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, relative-path

I'm having an issue where im reusing partial controls in my asp.net mvc project. The situation is that we the website can be accessed from 2 different paths: e.g.

1. `http://localhost/mywebsite`
2. `http://localhost/mywebsite/app/otherapp`

These two address share controls and on those shared controls there are some img html tags with relative addressing throughout.

i.e.

This relative image address works fine for address web address 1 but fails for web address 2. To get it working for web address 2 i need to change it to

I've got these throughout the entire system and it would be a nightmare to go through and switch them at runtime.

Wondering if there is someway to cover this situation without all the hassle?

Comment: How are you generating your `<img>` tags?

Comment: They're just coded into the html page.

Comment: Again, how are you generating your <img> tags (show the code)

Comment: <img alt="Ok" src='img/buttons/Ok.png' />

Answer (score 0):

You should use "~" in your "src" to start from your home directory:

```
<img alt="Ok" src='~/img/buttons/Ok.png' />
```

Comment: The tilde doesnt seem to work. The network tab says that it's looking for http://localhost/mywebsite/app/otherapp/~/img/buttons/Ok.png

Answer (score 0):

```
<img alt="img1" src='/img/buttons/Ok.png' />
```

or use Url.Action() method.

```
<img alt="img1" src="@Url.Action('')"/>
```

use Url.Action method overload of your choice.